# Can Firebase Data Messages be disabled by iPhone users?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Do Firebase Cloud Messaging [Data Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) need to be allowed by an iPhone user and can he disable them in the iPhone's Settings app?

[image: Example iOS dialog to allow notifications]

I know that this is required for "Notification Messages". But Firebase "Data Messages" seem different. I do **not** want to show any visible notification to the user. I just want to ping the iPhone app if and when data in the backend were updated to let the app know that it needs to refresh its data from the server. This is meant to happen in the background without the user noticing.

The aim is to avoid having the app frequently "pull" and ask the backend whether a data refresh is needed. But if "Data Messages" can be disabled by the user, I will not use them as a vehicle to keep critical app data in sync.

Thanks!